# How to implement accordian in lightning?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, accordion

Please help me in how to implement Lightning Accordian component.

I tried one solution from Internet but it is not working.

Will you please share some examples of it?

Accordian.cmp-

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name="closeOthers" type="boolean" default="true"/>
    <aura:attribute name="bootstrapStyles" type="boolean" default="true"/>

    <aura:handler event="c:AccordionOpenEvent" action="{!c.handleOpened}"/>

    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.bootstrapStyles}">
        <ltng:require scripts="/resource/jquery1_11,/resource/Bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"

                  styles="/resource/LDS102,/resource/Bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

    </aura:if>

    <div class="bs">{!v.body}</div>

</aura:component>
```

AccordianController-

```
({
    handleOpened : function(component, event) {
        //we only care if the closeOthers = true
        if (component.get("v.closeOthers")){
            console.log("rebroadcasting an event to the kids");
            var AccordionOpenEvent = $A.get("e.msmsf:PeerOpened");
            AccordionOpenEvent.setParams({
                "openedPanel" : event.getParam("openedPanel")
            });
            AccordionOpenEvent.fire();
        }
    }    
})
```

AccordianOpenEvent.evt

```
<aura:event type="APPLICATION" description="to be fired when an accordion panel is opened">
    <aura:attribute name="openedPanel" type="Aura.Component[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="accordionId" type="string"/>

</aura:event>
```

AccordianPanel.cmp

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name="panelHeading" type="Aura.Component[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="panelClass" type="string" default="panel panel-default"/>
    <aura:attribute name="open" type="boolean" default="false"/>

    <aura:registerEvent name="AccordionOpenEvent" type="c:AccordionOpenEvent"/>
    <!--aura:handler event="msmsf:AccordionOpenEvent" action="{!c.handleOpened}"/-->
    <aura:handler event="c:PeerOpened" action="{!c.handleOpened}"/>

    <div class="{!v.panelClass}">
        <div class="panel-heading" onclick="{!c.toggleOpen}">{!v.panelHeading}</div>
        <aura:renderIf isTrue="{!v.open}">
            <div class="panel-body">{!v.body}</div>        
        </aura:renderIf>
    </div>

</aura:component>
```

AccordianpanelController-

```
    ({
        toggleOpen : function(component, event) {
            component.set("v.open", !component.get("v.open"));
            //broadcast an event containing the header if opened
            if (component.get("v.open")){
                var AccordionOpenEvent = $A.get("e.msmsf:AccordionOpenEvent");
                AccordionOpenEvent.setParams({
                    "openedPanel" : component.get("v.panelHeading")
                });
                AccordionOpenEvent.fire();
            }
        },

    handleOpened : function(component, event){
        //if it's not me, I'm going to close
        if (component.get("v.panelHeading") != event.getParam("openedPanel")){
            component.set("v.open", false);
        }
    }
})
```

PeerOpened.evt

Comment: Helo, Can you please post the code which you've tried so far?.It would be helpful

Comment: Modified the question.

Comment: Getting error in below line-  <ltng:require scripts="/resource/jquery1_11,/resource/Bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"

                  styles="/resource/LDS102,/resource/Bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />